# Update second UIPickerView based off previous picker selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, cocoa-touch, uipickerview

At the moment, I have a list of name values in an array.

I am populating the first picker with the names using the array but I want to load specific values into the second picker based off what I chose in my first picker.

I am using a MySQL database to load the values and to get the data for the second array, I am using the following code:

```
- (void) getCustomData {
NSString *concat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",getYear, self.textField.text];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:concat];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

yearArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.count; i++){

    NSString *pYear = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"year"];

    [yearArray addObject:pYear];

}
```

}

getYear is just @"http://www.website.com/getData.php?year="

So this successfully makes an array called yearArray and populates it with the correct values.

But here is my problem...

I now need to populate the second picker view array with this data then reload the second picker view to show it when the first text field is updated (with the selection made by the first picker view).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with, your controller should implement the UIPickerViewDataSource and UIPickerViewDelegate protocols, the first being the way to provide data for the picker. When you have that in place, all you have to do is call the second picker's updateAllComponents method to have it refresh its content.
So a delegate method for detecting selection in the first picker:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
  if (pickerView == self.yearPicker) {
    // update your data array for the second picker first
    // then call the following 
    [self.monthPicker updateAllComponents];
  }
}
```